ASP.NET Core API : failed to connect to server - an invalid argument was supplied
application.json connection string:
"ConnectionString": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=nvedwsgt-ih.xyz.com:1999)(PORT=1999)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=NVEDWSTG)));User Id =NVDS_XXXXXX;Password=ABC1234;"

My function to connect to the Oracle database:
public static DataTable GetDataTableOracle(string SQL, string strParameter1, object objParameter1)
{
    var cntNV = GetNvisonConnectionString();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cntNV))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.BindByName = true;
            cmd.CommandText = SQL;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strParameter1))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(strParameter1, objParameter1);
            }

            using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }
    }

    return dt;
}

I've beaten my head against the wall trying to connect to the db. I have confirmed connection to the database using Oracle SQL Developer and CAN connect without issue using the same UN and PW credentials.
Whats the invalid argument I'm supplying?
Here's the stack trace, states invalid IP address. Makes no sense.

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string
---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x80004005): Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string
---> System.FormatException: An invalid IP address was specified.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10022): An invalid argument was supplied.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.IPAddressParser.Parse(ReadOnlySpan1 ipSpan, Boolean tryParse) at System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(String ipString) at OracleInternal.Network.TcpTransportAdapter.Connect(ConnectionOption conOption) at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.ConnectViaCO(ConnectionOption connOption, AddressResolution addrRes) at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor) at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor) at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName, ConnectionOption CO) at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
at NEDWebService2.DAL.Abstract.GetDataTableOracle(String SQL, String strParameter1, Object objParameter1) in C:\Users\watersja\source\repos\NEDWebService2_4_8_2024\NEDWebService2\DAL\Abstract.cs:line 91
at NEDWebService2.DAL.NED_NV.FindPersonByNIHUserNameALL(String nihSSOUsername) in C:\Users\watersja\source\repos\NEDWebService2_4_8_2024\NEDWebService2\DAL\NED_NV.cs:line 28
at NEDWebService2.Service._NED_NV.FindPersonByNIHUserNameALL(String UserName) in C:\Users\watersja\source\repos\NEDWebService2_4_8_2024\NEDWebService2\Service_NED_NV.cs:line 32
at NEDWebService2.Controllers.NVisionController.GetNEDRecordByNIHUsername(String UserName) in C:\Users\watersja\source\repos\NEDWebService2_4_8_2024\NEDWebService2\Controllers\NVisionController.cs:line 23
at lambda_method2(Closure, Object, Object[])
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I'm expecting it to hit the Oracle database and run the SQL query supplied. The SQL runs fine in Oracle SQL developer using the same credentials.

HOST=nvedwsgt-ih.xyz.com:1999 has the port number specified in it and you are specifying the port additionally. Can you try taking out the port 1999 from your HOST and try?

This..... "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=nvedwsgt-ih.xyz.com)(PORT=1999)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=NVEDWSTG)));User Id =NVDS_XXXXXX;Password=ABC1234;"    Results in a different error.
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
HResult=0x80004005
Message=ORA-12545: Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname
Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
StackTrace:

could you please make sure you firewall is allowed to access the port 1999 on nvedwsgt-ih.xyz.com from your application server. try to ping the hostname ping nvedwsgt-ih.xyz.com and check it can be resolved to an IP address from the machine where your application is running. set this connection string "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=nvedwsgt-ih.xyz.com)(PORT=1999)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=NVEDWSTG)));User Id=NVDS_XXXXXX;Password=ABC1234;" make sure there is no extra space or typo .

instead of DNS name try using IP address for a test
